# Button multiplying range data and button removing this multiplication

Tags: excel, vba

I have two buttons, "multiply by 0" and "show original value".

For the "multiply by 0" button, I have the below code, which works fine. What I need help with is the code for the second button, which would make the range that is multiplied by 0 back to its original number).

```
Public Sub MultiplyByZero()

Dim rngData As Range

Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Sheet LC").Range("I76:O103")
rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*0")

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Mathematically, multiplying by zero isn't a reversible operation since division by zero is undefined, so to show the original value you'll need to retain that value in your workbook. Why do you want to multiply a range by zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code may helps you.

1. Declare a global variable named **arr** so you can call it from anywhere - **Dim arr As Variant**
2. Before you multiple by zero we store the values in that array - **arr = .Range("A1:A5")**
3. At any time we can bring the values back - **.Range("B1:B5").Value = arr**

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Dim arr As Variant

   Public Sub MultiplyByZero()

       Dim rngData As Range
       Dim cell As Range

       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

           arr = ""

           Set rngData = .Range("A1:A5")

           arr = .Range("A1:A5")

           rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*0")

       End With

   End Sub

   Public Sub RestoreValues()

       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

           If Not IsEmpty(arr)=True Then
               .Range("A1:A5").Value = arr
           Else
               MsgBox "Array is empty."
           End If

       End With

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just one more question, I need to be able each button do a different task so button1 will multiply by 0 and button2 would call back the original array values. How could I seperate the above code into two Subs so I can link assign each one to a button? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you ! I need my range where the data is showing to be the same cells as those saved in the array. I tried to put the same A1:A5 in the .Range part of the code but it all comes up as blank. Do you know why?

Comment: Cloud you please try again?

Comment: Glad to hear that i help. If your are satisfy with the answer void for it to help others with the same question.

Comment: I voted already, unfortunately I need to build 15 reputatation points so my votes can show :) but as soon as I have my 15 points I will come back to the question and give it a vote!

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the cells I wanted to make equal to 0 had complex formulas and so it ended up creating a value error. I replaced the first Sub in your formula by .Clearcontents so that I wouldn't have the value error. This works fine but the second part no longer works as it works with IsEmpty. Do you know how I could change the second part so that I could call the array from cleared cells?

Comment: Try to modify the code using **If Not IsEmpty(arr) = True** or **If Not IsEmpty(arr) = False**

Answer (score 0):

Using a formula instead of a constant:

```
Public Sub MultiplyByZero()
    Dim rngData As Range, rngWork AS Range

    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Sheet LC").Range("I76:O103")
    For Each rngWork In rngData.Cells
        With rngWork
            If .HasFormula Then
                If Right(.Formula,2) <> "*0" Then .Formula = .Formula & "*0"
            Else
                .Formula = "=" & .Value & "*0"
            End If
        End With
    Next rngWork
End Sub

Public Sub DivideByZero()
    Dim rngData As Range, rngWork AS Range

    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Sheet LC").Range("I76:O103")
    For Each rngWork In rngData.Cells
        With rngWork
            If .HasFormula Then
                If Right(.Formula,2) = "*0" Then .Formula = Mid(.Formula, 1, Len(.Formula)-2)
            End If
        End With
    Next rngWork
End Sub
```

This will change `10` into `=10*0` and then back into `=10`

Comment: Hi thank you, unfortunately when I try it it says "end if without block if", I'm not sure what it means?

Comment: @AniABC Sorry, copy/paste error - wrote an `End If` instead of a `Next`